# pipenv module install fails with lmod modules enabled

Tags: linux, python, cluster, pip, computing-environment

Recently I've been experimenting with cluster computing/administration. I've got a small RasPi cluster with shared storage. On the NFS storage, Python 3.6 is installed to a folder. I'm using LMOD to enable dynamic loading of modules, and have it set up to automatically bootstrap the "module" command into bash/fish/zsh.

I started a python project and attempted to install NumPy using pipenv:

`pipenv install numpy`

however, the installation fails with:

```
ValueError: A valid Fortran version was not found in this string:

Modules based on Lua: Version 7.8.8  2018-10-26 15:12 -05:00
    by Robert McLay mclay@tacc.utexas.edu

module [options] sub-command [args ...]

Help sub-commands:
------------------
  help                              prints this message
  help                module [...]  print help message from module(s)

Loading/Unloading sub-commands:
-------------------------------
  load | add          module [...]  load module(s)
  try-load | try-add  module [...]  Add module(s), do not complain if not
                                    found
  del | unload        module [...]  Remove module(s), do not complain if not
                                    found
  swap | sw | switch  m1 m2         unload m1 and load m2
  purge                             unload all modules
  refresh                           reload aliases from current list of
                                    modules.
  update                            reload all currently loaded modules.

Listing / Searching sub-commands:
---------------------------------
  list                              List loaded modules
  list                s1 s2 ...     List loaded modules that match the
                                    pattern
  avail | av                        List available modules
  avail | av          string        List available modules that contain
                                    "string".
  spider                            List all possible modules
  spider              module        List all possible version of that module
                                    file
  spider              string        List all module that contain the
                                    "string".
  spider              name/version  Detailed information about that version
                                    of the module.
  whatis              module        Print whatis information about module
  keyword | key       string        Search all name and whatis that contain
                                    "string".

Searching with Lmod:
--------------------
  All searching (spider, list, avail, keyword) support regular expressions:


  -r spider           '^p'          Finds all the modules that start with
                                    `p' or `P'
  -r spider           mpi           Finds all modules that have "mpi" in
                                    their name.
  -r spider           'mpi$         Finds all modules that end with "mpi" in
                                    their name.
```

I think this is because pipenv is trying to call a program named 'module' during this step and instead of getting the program, it gets the bootstrap for LMOD. I'm not sure how to address the issue though. The same happens when I run pip directly:

`pip install --user numpy`

full output: https://pastebin.com/iBcydFfu

I'm at a loss on this one, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to install `numpy` on the ARM architecture, but there are no prebuilt wheels for ARM, only for x64 platform. `pip` thus tries to build `numpy` from source code and fails because you don't have anything configured for that. To build `numpy` from source, you need at least a C compiler (I suppose you have `gcc` already) and a Fortran compiler (`gfortran77`) for the minimal build of the extensions. See [Building from source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/building.html) for more details.

Comment: Aside from that, there are other options of installing `numpy` on RPi, from `apt install python3-numpy` to [piwheels](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/piwheels/). if you google for _numpy arm wheels_, you will also get some results like [this](https://gergely.imreh.net/wheels/numpy/), although the `numpy` version is not the newest one. `pip install numpy --extra-index-url=https://gergely.imreh.net/wheels/` will install the custom built wheels from that website.